# Request de datos de un formulario devuelve un objeto vacío

Tags: javascript, nodejs, backend

Estoy haciendo un formulario para editar datos, uso NodeJS y Express para el BackEnd y EJS como template engine.

La petición GET funciona como se espera:
Se busca un objeto en particular de una BD, se devuelve la información al controlador y esta se carga en la vista.

El problema aparece cuando se ejecuta la petición PUT:
Al momento de hacer click al botón que ejecuta el "action" del formulario, el objeto que debe llegar para guardar los cambios en la BD llega vacío ({}).

Algunas cosas que ya verifiqué:

1. Del lado del HTML, el formulario tiene los "label" e "input" bien armados y enlazados (cada input tiene su "name" e "id" aclarados y cada label tiene su "for" correspondiente).
2. El entry point está preparado para trabajar con datos de un formulario:

   ```
   app.use(express.urlencoded({ extended: false }));
   app.use(express.json());
   ```
3. Se está usando "method-override" para el uso de PUT y DELETE:

   ```
   const methodOverride = require('method-override');
   app.use(methodOverride('_method'));
   ```

   Y está implementado en el "action" del formulario":

   ```
   <form action="/movies/update/<%= Movie.id %>?_method=PUT" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">
   ```
4. Ya tengo un formulario para la creación de nuevos objetos que funciona de manera correcta.
5. La función en el controlador es la siguiente:

   ```
   ...
   save: function(req,res){
       console.log(req.body); <- //Esto devuelve "{}"
       db.Movie.update({
           title: req.body.title,
   ...
   ```